# Are deep passenger flight's details-like question on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Since I'm a passenger flights and general airlines enthusiast, I'd like to plan my travels and trips also depending on information on which kind of aircraft I'll be or can travel from point A to point B. For this reason, I'd like to ask some questions like "[What is the shortest in-Europe commercial route that I can travel on Boeing 747](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30789/3230)" etc.

This particular question is found off-topic on Aviation.se and [I was told that](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3081/3230) these kind of questions are also generally off-topic for that site.

And on Travel.se? Can such questions be on-topic here or should I avoid asking them here as well?

Comment: sounds great to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That sounds on-topic to me.
If it's a journey you want to do, as a traveller, then it seems askable here.
We've even got a bunch of factoid questions, which do get a mixed response, but are generally left open.

(We've got questions about longest train/bus journeys etc).

As ever, some specifics to narrow things down a little often help make it more of a "real" question and less "gather lots of data for me".

Answer (score 3):

I most certainly think that such a question would be entertained here, as long as you stay [on-topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (and make it useful also for other users).

For your particular question, while not exactly the same, I think this would be a good starting point for further research:

[How to find and compare flights carried out by a specific type of plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46093/32134)

Answer (score 1):

I've personally never liked these questions for the site whether or not I've liked them as interesting stuff.

However, the users as a group have accepted them. This is the precise type of question the [factoids](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factoids) was created for.

Usually they're not for problems faced by a traveller but for biggest longest shortest fastest quietest highest kinda stuff.